# text-align: right; Not Woking

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.I have minimized it as short as I can. In that `text-align:right;` is not working

```css
.forgot {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <center>
    <h3><u>LOREM IPSUM</u></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot details?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: text-align on the parent element not the element

Comment: use float: right; instead

Comment: @ReaganGallant don't suggest `float: right` - it's a bad practice (especially in this case) that can cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @treyBake what kind of unexpected behaviour? The OP gave no description or context

Comment: @ReaganGallant a simple google of `float bugs` will quickly show just how many posts there are for it.

Comment: as a note: `center` is obsolete and `u` is no longer used. Use `text-align: center` in your css and `<em>` in place of `u`

Comment: @treyBake There's nothing wrong with using Float if used correctly. Please read up on how to use it here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: @ReaganGallant but with things like proper use of `display` and `flex layouts` - what's the point in taking the risk?

Answer (score 2):

As @TreyBake pointed out, `center` and `u` are not supposed to be used instead, you should use the text-align and em.

Also, here's the solution with setting right align to parent.

```css
.forgot {
  color: red;
}

.center-aligned{
text-align: center;
}

.right-aligned{
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="center-aligned">
    <h3><em>LOREM IPSUM</em></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="right-aligned">
  <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot details?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bernhard had mentioned that using 'text-align: right' will do the job, in your answer you have used on the parent as well as element which seems repetitive.

Comment: @user1579234 He added that to `content` class. When you have lot of elements in `content` div, changing the `content` styles is bit risky. It is always better to pack items. Also, I forgot to remove that from the OP's code copied.

Answer (score 0):

The align is set on the parent element. Not on the element itself.

```css
.forgot {
  color: red;
}

.content {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <center>
    <h3><u>LOREM IPSUM</u></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot details?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: right` on a parent element. Create a `div` wrapping your link and give him the class. See example below:

html:

```
<div class="content">
  <center>
    <h3><u>LOREM IPSUM</u></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <div class="text-right">
    <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot details?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.forgot {
  color: red;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

If you have Bootstrap installed, you can do all of this without css. Your html would look like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <center>
    <h3><u>LOREM IPSUM</u></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <div class="text-right">
   <a href="#" class="text-danger">Forgot details?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note at time of writing, this is Bootstrap v4.2.1

Comment: @Corné not 100% sure tbh, your answer works - though I guess the use of obsolete tags may make some devs downvote

Comment: Yes, I also think that is it, altough his tags says `html` and `css`, not `html5` and `css3`

Comment: @Corné true, though I think HTML5 and CSS3 have become the latest standard to adhere to, so I guess html = html5 now and not html4

Comment: Make sense, yes. Still don't think it's worth a down vote when you answer the specific question that is being asked. :)

Comment: @Corné S'pose that's up to the admins to decide :) but for what it's worth I won't downvote :)

Comment: @treyBake, much appreciated! =D

Answer (score 0):

**Here's Why It's Not Aligning**

You have your `<a class="forgot">` element with the "Forgot Details" text inside of it. Since it's an `<a>` element, by default it will only stretch to be as wide as the text you place inside it. So as you can see in the screenshot below, your `<a class="forgot">` element (highlit) is only as wide as the "Forgot Details" text. So your `"text-align: right;"` technically *is* aligning the text to the right, but since the parent container (the `<a class="forgot">` element) is only as wide as the text, horizontally aligning it doesn't make a difference.

[image]
**How To Fix It**

Where an `<a>` element stretches only to fit its contents, a `<div>` element by default stretches horizontally to fill its parent container. So what you can do is enclose your `<a class="forgot">` in a `<div class="forgot-parent">`, and then apply the `"text-align: right"` to the `<div class="forgot-parent">` so that the `<a class="forgot">` gets aligned to the right.

So the code will look like this:

```
.forgot {
  color: red;
}
.forgot-parent {
  text-align: right;
}

<div class="content">
  <center>
    <h3><u>LOREM IPSUM</u></h3><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login as Guest</button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <div class="forgot-parent">
    <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot details?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note how I removed `"text-align: right;"` from `'.forgot'` and added it to `'.forgot-parent'`. The result is shown below. First, here is the parent `<a class="forgot-parent">` div highlit.

[image]

Note how the `<div class="forgot-parent">` has stretched to the full screen width. Next the `<a class="forgot">` is highlit:

[image]

Note that the `<a class="forgot">` is still only the width of its contents (the "Forgot Details" text), but it's now aligned to the right within its parent div.